# Can ANTLR 4 parse a non prefix-free language?

Tags: parsing, compilation, antlr, antlr4

I've recently begun using ANTLR 4. After quite a lot of testing, I wonder **if ANTLR 4 can parse a non prefix-free context-free language**. That's because its parsers seem to only make the parse tree out of the longest-from-the-start valid substring of input string.

For example, in the parsing stage of this grammar

```
grammar Hello;
r  : 'hello' ID ;
ID : [a-z]+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

and this input string

```
hello sir hello sir
```

, the parser seems to only parse one *hello sir*. So, the input string seems to be valid in the grammar, but actually it's not.

Being aware of the fact that I might know about ANTLR enough, I've googled quite a lot about the problem but got no results. Although I might haven't searched it in the right way, now I think it's better to just ask the pros.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Please provide an example. ANTLR has a separate lexer stage, you may want to read about [its rules here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201610201441331384843).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I've added an example. My question is actually about the parser stage.

Comment: ... only parses one *hello sir*.   Right, that's what your grammar says is legal.   I presume it then complains that there is additional, unconsumed input? (My DMS parsers do).  Please show us the output of a parser run, and tell us precisely what you think is wrong about it.

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Either add `EOF` to the `r` rule to force the parser to fail `r: 'hello' ID EOF;`, or write `r: ('hello' ID)+ EOF;` to get a valid parse.

Comment: @IraBaxter by default ANTLR just leaves the input token stream with the current position set to the first unconsumed token - you have to explicitly add `EOF` to the start rule if you want it to complain about additional input.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: (or check that the input stream is empty).  This may be the source of  OP's misunderstanding.  Cleared up my understanding of his problem :-}

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That's exactly my problem. Thank you (I cannot thumb-up for now).

Comment: @IraBaxter Although the original question is answered, just out of curiosity, how can I make the parser complain about unconsumed input? After running TheParser.r(), I used ParseTreeWalker to walk the tree, and everything turns out to alright, that leads to my misunderstanding.

Comment: @VincentJ.Ruan  I'm not an ANTLR-detail expert; I just know lot about parsing.   I think Lucas told you how to do this; in your shoes I'd follow his advice about  the EOF.  Surely the ANTLR docs tell you about this somewhere.